# '....has long been...' or '...has been long....'

Tags: grammar

[OALD's entry's example:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shun?q=shun)

> *The company **has long been** shunned by ethical investors.*

I always get confused with word order (unless they are 'adjectives' for what I know the order).

The example is there. Why not *'...has been long...'*?

As a non-native speaker, I'd be cautious splitting 'has been'. Is it possible to keep those words intact?

Comment: *Long* in the first example is an adverb, not an adjective--= "**for** a long time"--so its most natural place is after the first auxiliary. In the second example it's an adjective fused with its 'head'--"a long time"--so it takes the predicate complement place.

Comment: Ah, I just skipped it. Changing! @StoneyB

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to keep "has been" intact, but it's less natural.

In that context, the word "long" is an *adverb*, as [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long) says:

> **long** *adverb*
> **1 :** for or during a long time
> *long a popular hangout*

It's correct and natural to split perfect structures with adverbs, including passive perfect forms. These examples have the most natural word order:

> He has **never** worked hard.
> These books have **all** been returned with new damage.

So splitting these verbs is not an issue to be avoided.

With this function, "long" always comes *before* the thing it modifies, so these versions are also grammatically correct, though much more formal sounding than the original:

> The company has been **long** shunned by ethical investors.
> **Long** has the company been shunned by ethical investors.

And these versions are bad grammar:

> *The company has been shunned **long** by ethical investors.
> *The company has been shunned by ethical investors **long**.

Answer (score -1):

This is to emphasis the word 'long'.  
 
If you need to emphasize a specific fact or point in your text, there are several ways to focus the reader’s attention on it. This is one of those.  
 
Eg:

> It was the strangest piece of music I **had** ever **heard**.
>
> *Here, the word 'ever' is emphasized.*